# How to pass parameter on JQuery .trigger of html button from different html page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

In my angular component, on click of button, I am showing alert pop-up.
code is like this--
My html code is:

```
<button id="subtreeAlert" (click)="showsubtreeAlert(alertMessage)"></button>
```

My ts code is:

```
showsubtreeAlert(message){
        this.alertMessage =  message;
        this.alertType = 'warning';
        $('#alertBox').modal({backdrop: "static", keyboard: false, show: true});
    }
```

But i need to trigger this code from other javascript file using jquery:
code is:

```
function A(){
            var activeMessage = "xyzz";
             window.parent.parent.$('#subtreeAlert').trigger('click',activeMessage);
}
```

Problem is, I am able trigger the button and can see popup, but alertMessage is empty string.

How to pass this?

Comment: The button is hard coded to run showsubtreeAlert(alertMessage) - passing a parameter to the trigger click call won't change alertMessage.  Can't you just call showsubtreeAlert(activeMessage) from A() instead of trying to trigger a click?

Comment: Actually, showsubtreeAlert() function is in angular ts file, And I need it to be called from A() that is in jsp file.
Triggering hidden button click was easiest way to do that.
I dont know how to directly call method of angular ts from jsp.